# How to enable debug logging with Libwebsockets?

Tags: c, debugging, cmake, libwebsockets

I'm trying to implement a websocket client (with libwebsockets in C). I'm using cmake to control the software compilation process.

My question is simple : **How to enable debug logging with Libwebsockets ?**

First i compiled and installed libwebsockets like it said in the documentation *Notes about building lws* :

> To build with debug info and _DEBUG for lower priority debug messages
>   compiled in, use
>
> $ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG

From **Libwebsockets 2.1** doc *Notes about coding with lws* 
(https://libwebsockets.org/lws-api-doc-master/html/md_README.coding.html) :

> Debug Logging
>
> Also using lws_set_log_level api you may provide a custom callback to
>   actually emit the log string. By default, this points to an internal
>   emit function that sends to stderr. Setting it to NULL leaves it as it
>   is instead.
>
> A helper function lwsl_emit_syslog() is exported from the library to
>   simplify logging to syslog. You still need to use setlogmask, openlog
>   and closelog in your user code.
>
> The logging apis are made available for user code.
>
> lwsl_err(...) lwsl_warn(...) lwsl_notice(...) lwsl_info(...)
>   lwsl_debug(...) The difference between notice and info is that notice
>   will be logged by default whereas info is ignored by default.
>
> If you are not building with _DEBUG defined, ie, without this
>
> $ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG then log levels below notice do
>   not actually get compiled in.

Like in [this (official) example](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/v2.1-stable/test-server/test-client.c), i put `lws_set_log_level(10, NULL);` at the beginning of my websocket main function.

CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(foo)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG) #For CLion IDE but i'm pretty sur it does nothing.

set(SOURCE_FILES
        websocket.c
        websocket.h
        main.c)

add_executable(foo ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(foo websockets)
```

Then i run cmake :

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG
make
```

Everything works fine, my websocket client seems ok.

But i've no debug logs... What am i missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tks to the *lws-team* on Github :**

> The build type of DEBUG stops more verbose logging types from being
>   removed during build.
>
> You still need to enable them at runtime using a bitmap in
>   lws_set_log_level()... **the default is 7** (err / warn / notice)

I misread **libwebsockets.h :**

```
    enum lws_log_levels {
    LLL_ERR = 1 << 0,
    LLL_WARN = 1 << 1,
    LLL_NOTICE = 1 << 2,
    LLL_INFO = 1 << 3,
    LLL_DEBUG = 1 << 4,
    LLL_PARSER = 1 << 5,
    LLL_HEADER = 1 << 6,
    LLL_EXT = 1 << 7,
    LLL_CLIENT = 1 << 8,
    LLL_LATENCY = 1 << 9,
    LLL_USER = 1 << 10,

    LLL_COUNT = 11 /* set to count of valid flags */
};
```

Like Andy said, the default is *0000 0111*, so 7...